# gradle plugin that used data from other plugin declared in main build

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-plugin

How to use aplicationId from

```
apply plugin: PublishApkToUpdateServerPlugin

version = '1.0'

class PublishApkToUpdateServerPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task('uploadapk') << {
            logger.lifecycle("appId ${android.defaultConfig.applicationID}");
        }
    }
}
```

my problem is here **android.defaultConfig.applicationID**

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':uploadapk'.
>     Could not find property '**android**' on task ':uploadapk'.

How to use properties declared at other plugin and used in main build script?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess you are missing a namespace in front of uploadapk like

```
project.task('com.externalinc:uploadapk')
```

and its trying to use android:uploadapk instead. Try playing around with it.

Comment: no, i have one build.gradle  with PublishApkToUpdateServerPlugin i call it plugin. And i have other build gradle on other level where i try to use this plugin.